# How Combine List with Repository (table)

Tags: c#

I had two lists and one Repository (one Table). 
Table has more columns but important columns are `Id and ShippingNumbers(list of number)`
I should combine this of three according to date (which Id contains date) and Shipping Numbers

**List1**

```
var IdsList =new string[] {
"A-28.03.18-B",
"S-17.05.18-G",
"L-17.05.18-P",
"M-28.03.18-T",
"B-17.05.18-U" };
```

**List2**

```
var ShippingNumbersList =new string[] {
                    "100,200,300",
                    "100,900",
                    "200,300,100",
                    "100,900,300",
                    "100,300" };
```

**Table**

```
TemplateRepository = {
  Id: "Z-28.03.18-K",  ShippingNumbers: "100,600",
  Id: "P-17.05.18-R",  ShippingNumbers: "900",
  Id: "T-28.03.18-L",  ShippingNumbers: "300" }
```

I can combine List1 and List2, however I can't combine result list with repository.Below you can find what I did:

```
IList<string> myList = new List<string>();
var normalizedlist = IdsList 
            .Select((Ids, index) => new { Ids = Ids, ShippingNumbers = ShippingNumbersList [index].Split(',') })
            .ToList();
        foreach (var ShippingNumber in normalizedlist.SelectMany(x => x.ShippingNumbers).Distinct())
        {
            //fitering and then grouping by date 
            var filtered = normalizedlist.Where(y => y.ShippingNumbers.Contains(ShippingNumber))
                .GroupBy(y => y.Ids.Split('-')[1])
                .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
                .Select(y => y.Select(z => z.Ids));
            foreach (var date in filtered)
            {
                myList.Add(ShippingNumber + ">>" + string.Join(",", date.ToArray()));
            }
        }
```

**Output:**

```
100>>A-28.03.18-B,M-28.03.18-T
100>>S-17.05.18-G,L-17.05.18-P,B-17.05.18-U
300>>A-28.03.18-B,M-28.03.18-T
300>>L-17.05.18-P,B-17.05.18-U
```

I should combine this with Template Repository ,after combining the result will be:

**Expected Output:**

```
100>>A-28.03.18-B,M-28.03.18-T,Z-28.03.18-K
100>>S-17.05.18-G,L-17.05.18-P,B-17.05.18-U
300>>A-28.03.18-B,M-28.03.18-T,T-28.03.18-L
300>>L-17.05.18-P,B-17.05.18-U
900>>S-17.05.18-G,P-17.05.18-R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your `TemplateRepository` to the other lists.

```
IdsList.AddRange(TemplateRepository.Select(x => x.Id));
ShippingNumbersList.AddRange(TemplateRepository.Select(x => x.ShippingNumbers));
```

And now call your combine method for `IdsList` and `ShippingNumbersList`.

If you don't want to modify the `IdsList` and `ShippingNumbersList`, simply create a new list with both information.

```
var newIdsList = IdsList.Concat(TemplateRepository.Select(x => x.Id)).ToList();
var newShippingNumbersList = ShippingNumbersList.Concat(TemplateRepository.Select(x => x.ShippingNumbers)).ToList();
```

And now you have to call your combine method for `newIdsList` and `newShippingNumbersList`.

(As a friendly reminder, please mark answers as accepted in your questions)